# Find the number of distinct elements.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\omega$ denote a non-real cube root of unity. Then find the number of distinct elements in the set $\{ (1+\omega + \omega^2 + \cdots + \omega^n)^m | m,n \in \Bbb Z_+ \}$

Comment: Why do you use the sum symbol? Aren't you adding the same element $n+1$ times?

Comment: @LeifSabellek edited

Comment: Careful using $i$ as an iterator in a complex number problem.

Comment: Calculate the inner sum for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$ (ignoring $m$ at the moment) and see if you spot a pattern you can exploit.

Comment: For $n=1$ you already get infinitely many elements, since $|1+\omega|>1$. EDIT: No, im wrong. It is $|1+\omega|=1$.

Comment: He changed the problem, it should iterate from the first power, not the zeroth.

Answer (score 0):

See the $1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^n$ part cycles $\mod 3$. So it suffices to consider $n=0,1,2,3$. For larger values we get one of these four values. Now this gives the part under parentheses is $\{1, -\omega^2, 0, \omega\}$. Now see $m$ cycles $\mod 3$. Thus check for $n=1, 2, 3$.
So the set of values is $\{1, -\omega^2,\omega, -1, 0, \omega, \omega^2\}$. I think this is all of it.

Comment: How do you prove the initial claim you made?

Comment: Why you put w twice in the set?